# Need advice on creating clone, fork, or branch of my current project

Tags: project-management, branch, fork

I have been using both git and svn for quite some time now, and as the time passes, and my projects become more complex, I am starting to know how projects are actually managed.

Now I already know the basic concepts of forking and branching. With forking you will create a clone of the existing project, in which you can work. With branching you keep working in the same project, but you just go a different direction.

I know this, but I can still not decide which to choose, because I do not want to end up choosing the wrong method. That's why I am asking some advice.

--

The projects I am working on is a website. The website is finished and running for the public. I still have two tasks to complete, and they are:

1) Because the website is just launched, I still make small daily changes. Some SEO related, some minor browser fixes, some small content changes. Basically I still make small changes to the project.

2) The second task I have is expanding the current project. I am creating some private content that will not be visible to the public, but it belongs to the same project. They are pages that will be used by the company intern.

So basically I will need to work on the current project, and on the fork / branch. Eventually, when the private pages are done, it will become 1 project again.

Now the question is, should I create a branch or a fork of the current project.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about git, svn, or neither?

Comment: Consider http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I am using SVN in this project. And I will check out the link. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the difference is simple. If you are creating a fork, then you never intend to put your new work in the fork back into the thing you forked from.

If you intend to put your work back, then you want a branch. In your cases you certainly want to branch. Of course you can choose to abandon a branch if you decide that it does not work out. Each of the VCS tools has a means of managing branches to allow you to merge the changes back to the master/trunk (the code line from which you branched).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so your suggestion is a branch. But I was wondering one thing, when I create a branch, can I work on both ends of the branch, or should I only work on the created branch?

Comment: By both ends, you mean the thing you started with and the branch. The answer is yes, that's the whole point. In general when you do a major release of software you branch so that you can continue your development in the trunk/master and then you can do maintenance fixes in the branch (and release those to customers). As you apply these fixes to the branch, they will also need to get applied to the trunk/master. So the whole idea is to allow two code streams to go in parallel.